# Post comment on note via Javascript SDK

Tags: post, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am attempting to use the JavaScript SDK to post a note from my site and then allow a comment to be posted to that note immediately following.  I am successful in the first part.  Here is a relevant snippet:

```
alert('posting to path (' + path + ') with params (' + JSON.stringify(params) + ')');
FB.api(path, "post", params, function(response) {
    if (response.error) {
        alert(response.error.type + ": " + response.error.message);
    } else {... do stuff ...}
```

Notice that I am dumping the variables I am passing for inspection.  The results go like this:

**When posting the note:**

```
posting to path (/100003217376622/notes) with params ({"access_token":"AAAChRmSu9s8BACFDhWCFnIS8R3OTZCSxZAyL4hLbAQxGUrn0t4ksZC5CS62qlLtAIconOKCreAUpaorzOZCHkxp2DlTfcc2c8vOY5MOLPdHMqdfWMu2V","subject":"Note #1","message":"My note"})
```

This works fine and the number preceding "/notes" is my profile id.

However, I subsequently try to post a comment to that note and end up with the following.

**When posting a comment to that note:**

```
posting to path (/124528970997681/comments) with params ({"access_token":"AAAChRmSu9s8BACFDhWCFnIS8R3OTZCSxZAyL4hLbAQxGUrn0t4ksZC5CS62qlLtAIconOKCreAUpaorzOZCHkxp2DlTfcc2c8vOY5MOLPdHMqdfWMu2V","message":"Comment on Note # 1"})
```

This results in an error, shown below:

```
OAuthException: (#200) Cannot access object_id: 124528970997681
```

The number preceding "/comments" is, in fact, the id of the note, as when I hover over the note link on my wall, I see this URL: http://www.facebook.com/notes/danja-garno/note-1/124528970997681, which does lead me to the note.

Any idea why I would be getting this error?

============================= **UPDATE** =================================

This morning I posted a link instead of a note and then successfully posted a comment via the same form and code.

Now, I did notice two things that may provide a clue.  First, the permalink for the **link** looks like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=285359141511345&id=100003217376622
```

While the permalink for the **note** looks like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/notes/danja-garno/note-this-note/127723150678263
```

**ALSO**, when I directly access these objects via the Graph API URL, I get two different responses.

I got a valid response for the **link** using this URL https://graph.facebook.com/141246962656776?access_token=AAAChRmSu9s8BAKedPE9DyZB5W0lQYgn71WkFFtR0wIBMHp3Qgr09vmZA7YhvzJbgoigQRHsaqXqOhpmrbzdhWd6QYV8jHvsKjSVMpLZBTD8GI9Lax7p

**BUT**, when I tried to access the **note** in the same way using this URL https://graph.facebook.com/124528970997681?access_token=AAAChRmSu9s8BAKedPE9DyZB5W0lQYgn71WkFFtR0wIBMHp3Qgr09vmZA7YhvzJbgoigQRHsaqXqOhpmrbzdhWd6QYV8jHvsKjSVMpLZBTD8GI9Lax7p

All it returned was "false".  What's up with that?

Comment: Great question!  Are you able to post a comment to the note at a later time?

Comment: @DMCS => If I go to my wall, sure.  But my application only gives the user the opportunity to "post a comment to the last post" and once you leave the page, that ability is gone.  It is structured to allow you to add a comment immediately following your post from within my application and that's about it.

Comment: Ok, so then it's clearly a timing issue and you cannot immediately put a comment onto a new post. I suggest you that queue that comment for later processing (say 1 minute) and see if that works.  Adjust the hold time of your queue until you get the best performance.

Comment: I did some testing and it's not a timing issue.  The problem is that I can't access the note object.  This is supported by the fact that the note is inaccessible via the graph URL. See the update in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get some time to try this out.

I can post a note, then post a comment to that note via the Graph API.  I still think it's a timing issue where the graph is sluggish to cross save the note in all the places it needs to (and the graph's database may be the last datastore to be replicated). So I would suggest placing the comment into a hold queue for processing at a later time (maybe give it 1 minute).